# Use of local macro

Tags: if-statement, stata, stata-macros

I want to write six temp data files from my original data keeping the following variables:

- temp1: v1-v18
- temp2: v1-v5 v19-v31
- temp3: v1-v5 v32-v44
- temp4: v1-v5 v45-v57
- temp5: v1-v5 v58-v70
- temp6: v1-v5 v71-v84

I have tried the following:

```
forvalues i =1(1)6 { 
    preserve
    local j = 6 + (`i'-1)*13
    local k = `j'+12
    keep v1-v18 if `j'==6
    keep v1-v5 v`i'-v`k' if `i'>6 & `j'<71
    keep v1-v5 v71-v84 if `j'==71
    export delimited using temp`i'.csv, delimiter(";") novarnames replace
    restore 
}
```

I get an `invalid syntax` error. The problem lies with the `keep` statements. Specifically the `if` condition with a local macro seems to be against syntax rules.

Comment: Please be sure to up-vote answers that are helpful and flag answers as accepted if they provide a solution.  This gives us points and encourages the community to grow!

Comment: @ander2ed gives a very good diagnosis but it follows from the `help` for `keep` that you can can `keep` a _varlist_ or `keep` certain observations using an `if` qualifier **but not both at the same time**. That is almost certainly the immediate problem (although you don't provide a reproducible example, as your code depends on your datasets). There is no problem with combining an `if` qualifier and local macros so long as the syntax is legal otherwise.

Comment: Not the question, but a situation in which six individual `keep` statements would have been much shorter and much quicker to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your confusion is due to misunderstanding the `if` qualifier vs the `if` command.

The `if` command evaluates an expression: if that expression is true, it executes what follows. The `if` command should be used to evaluate a single expression, in this case, the value of a macro.

You might use an `if` qualifier, for example, when you want to `regress y x if x > 2` or `replace x = . if x <= 2` etc. See [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/) for a short description.

Your syntax has other issues too. You cannot have code following on the same line as the open brace in your `forvalues` loop, or again on the same line as your closing brace. You also use the local `i` to condition your `keep`. I think you mean to use `j` here, as `i` simply serves to iterate the loop, not identify a variable suffix.

Further, the logic here seems to work, but doesn't seem very general or efficient. I imagine there is a better way to do this but I don't have time to play around with it at the moment - perhaps an update later.

In any case, I think the correct syntax most analogous to what you have tried  is something like the following.

```
clear *

set more off
set obs 5
forvalues i = 1/84 {
    gen v`i' = runiform()
}


forvalues i =1/6 { 
    preserve
    local j = 6 + (`i'-1)*13
    local k = `j'+12
    if `j' == 6 {
        keep v1-v18
    }
    else if `j' > 6 & `j' < 71 {
        keep v1-v5 v`j'-v`k'
    }
    else keep v1-v5 v71-v84
    ds
    di
    restore 
}
```

I use `ds` here to simply list the variables in the data followed by `di` do display a blank line as a separator, but you could simply plug back in your `export` and it should work just fine.

Another thing to consider if you truly want temp data files is to consider using `tempfile` so that you aren't writing anything to disk. You might use

```
forvalues i = 1/6 {
    tempfile temp`i'
    // other commands
    save `temp`i''
}
```

This will create six Stata data files `temp1` - `temp6` that are held in memory until the program terminates.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. For some reason, I thought STATA didnt have if block statements. I am glad to see that it does. The difference between qualifier and command is still a tricky one imo, but I get the general idea. I knew about commands just before or after brackets thing, but I couldnt get it to display right on this site.